# Is this an error in Guaraldi's Christmas Time is Here?

Tags: piano, chords, chord-theory, jazz

In the following fragment of *Christmas Time is Here* in Guaraldi's *A Charlie Brown Christmas*, which is in the key of F, there's a chord that is notated D♭9 but is written with a natural A giving it a sharpened fifth.

[image]

Which is more likely correct, the D♭9 or should the A be flat?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a D chord with a flat 9 instead of a D-flat chord with a 9?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'd say it is Db, the tritone substitution of G7, which leads to C

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that's a usual suspect that's tripped me up a few times! But with F, Eb, Cb and A it can't be . 5th A and b9 Eb fit but that's all. Tts as Shev says, is a good possibility, which makes the A not fit well. Tts usually are dom. 7ths. Since the A is also in the melody line, it could be a #5. This is one place where an accidental would make sense!

Comment: The augmented fifth is common in this book and I would not put it past Guaraldi. But, to my ear, the perfect sounds better, and the flow from the G in the Gm7 through the A♭ in the D♭9 to the A in the C13 is very typical of the (beautiful) progressions I've found throughout the book (you can see an E->E♭->D in the prior measure and a E♭->D->D♭ in the next), so, given the D♭9 notation, I'm inclined to believe the ♭ for the A was omitted "accidentally."

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @PaulJackson .  Paul you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an Ab was intended then there would be a mistake in the melody as well as in the accompaniment. The Ab would normally resolve down to the note G, not up to A (over C13). I'm sure that the A is the correct and intended note. There is no problem with a #5 in a tritone substitution. The Db9(#5) chord is a tritone substitution of G9(#5), which is of course the secondary dominant of C13. The appropriate chord scale is the whole tone scale. The desired effect appears to be the constant melody note A over a parallel downward movement from Db9 to C9.

Comment: While I'm not qualified to make an official ruling, I find your point about the melody very convincing. Played by itself, the melody doesn't sound right with the A♭. I hadn't noticed this before. Thank you to all for the feedback. I don't have the reputation to upvote or else I would.

Comment: Just to make explicit an important part of this answer: the *accompaniment* plays a straight Db9 chord, so the symbol in the sheet music is correct. The A is included in the chord, because the arrangement allows for the keyboard to play both the accompaniment and melody. This can be heard in the [soundtrack recording at 1:02](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PzetPqepXA&t=1m2s).

Answer (score 3):

Db9 is used as a dominant chord.One of the common jazz substitutions is to add an augmented chord where the dominant 7th chord would be. So, that is why you see that A natural  (#5) there and not a Ab (natural 5). This would be called an '[altered dominant chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_chord)', which means you could also have used: b5, (#5,) b9, #9 etc

<sub>Db works as a dominant because it is a tritone substitution of G7 and leads to C.</sub>

By the way, this might be a typo. The author might have wanted to add a flat to that A, and simply forgot it. It makes sense either way.

Comment: I was afraid of this. So you're saying either way could be correct. Any take on which is most likely the author's intent?

Comment: Since this sounds like a jazzy tune, I would #5 is correct; it is common in jazz